# web page Responsiveness with Apple devices

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, ipad

### Web page responsiveness with APPLE devices

i have various web pages ,that are responsive using various media queries that are working for various and operating system except apple devices and os(ios,ipad,iphone)
Now my pages are not responsive with apple devices.I have used  
but still it is not working.please suggest me some way.

Comment: Please provide code examples so we can see if there is something wrong.

Comment: This is not a question. This is madness.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no difference in regards to the responsiveness on different platforms. It doesen't matter which browser (e.g. Safari on Apple devices) you use. Unless it's an antiquated version of Safari.

Maybe you have coded your media query wrong? Here is an Example how one should look like:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) {
       /* your css here */
}
```

In this example your css will take effect when the browser window is less than 1200px wide.

Hopefully this helped you a little bit.